# Pass value from component to service and update variable in the service with new value come from component

Tags: angular

I have login component. After login appId is set in local storage also need to update in the service AppId object. The service contain header Key "AppId" this AppId's value take from login Component or local storage.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebconfigService {
baseUrl = "https://localhost:44330/api/";
AppId=""
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,){
      this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'AppId' :This.AppId
        })
      };
    }
    get(path: string,): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+path, this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }

    SetTokenFromLogin(appId){
       this.AppId=appId
    }
}
```

After login AppId is not passing to service. From login Method I pass value like this.

```
this.authService.LoginUser(LoginForm.value).subscribe((data)=>
      { this.webConfigService.SetTokenFromLogin(data["data"]["user"]["appId"])
})
```

Comment: It seem like `this.webConfigService.SetTokenFromLogin(this.token,data["data"]["user"]["appId"])` is passing `token` to the method, not appId

Comment: I don't understand how that can possibly compile, unless the service is typed as `any`. `This` is also invali TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the function inside the `subcribe()` showing that it passing the `token` in your component into the service's `AppId` property.

Correct it by:

```
this.authService.LoginUser(LoginForm.value).subscribe((data)=>{
   this.webConfigService.SetTokenFromLogin(data["data"]["user"]["appId"]);
})
```

---

Upate:

As I see you setting your **`HttpOptions`** inside the **`contructor`** which only evaluated once when the service start. Which mean the `AppId` property inside your `HttpOptions` always have the value of empty string.

Your logic should be setting the HttpOptions inside the `SetTokenFromLogin()` after you receive the API response.

```
 SetTokenFromLogin(appId){
    this.httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'AppId' :appId
       })
    };
 }
```

Comment: but after login next request not update AppId in header

Comment: It is becase you are setting your `httpOptions` inside the constructor which only evaluated once when the service run. Your logic should be setting the HttpOptions inside the `SetTokenFromLogin()` , not from the constructor.

Comment: Updated the answer